# Xpath partial matching search of an RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, xpath, rss

I have a web page setup that uses simple XML to retrieve an RSS feed then it is echoed onto the page.  I am trying to set up a search feature that will allow users to type in a query for the RSS feed then it will show the results on the page.

I know you can use Xpath contains

```
/item[contains(title, 'query')]/description
```

however I want the "query" section of this to be replaced with whatever is typed into the search box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated or a link to a relevant site with the answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NOTE: I consider the application language you are seeking solution in is PHP:

You will need to put the search keyword dynamically in the below fashion:

> **//item[contains(title,'".$searchKeyword."')]/description**

Below is the example:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
        <photographer>John</photographer>
        <image>a</image>
    </area>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
        <photographer>John</photographer>
        <image>b</image>
    </area>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
        <photographer>John</photographer>
        <image>c</image>
    </area>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>2</photographer_id>
        <photographer>Fred</photographer>
        <image>a</image>
    </area>
</root>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$searchKeyword = "Fred";
$area = $sxe->xpath("//area[contains(photographer,'".$searchKeyword."')]");

print_r($area);
```

Comment: Thanks that does clear it up a lot more for me. The $searchKeyword variable would what is typed into the search box so would I use post on the form that the search box is in and store that as the variable to use within $area?

Comment: yes you got it right. The search keyword will contain the posted value from the search box

Comment: Daniel if you find this answer helpful. Do up vote it. It will be a moral buster. Thanks!

Comment: Also, as the XML that is going to be used would be retrieved from a URL would I need to replace everything between your <root> tags with:

$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.url.asp');

Comment: Yes, you will have to... the xml i have mentioned is for example. if it is coming from any url then you will have to use what you have wrote i.e. $rss = simplexml_load_file('url.asp'); , if it is going to be coming as a string then $rss = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);